# What does this MSVC symbol mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I noticed this little sign on a project source file and didn't know what it meant.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the file has been configured to be ignored (not compiled) in the project.

The specific option is called 'Exclude From Build' in the General property.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Steve's answer, I would add:

- Your project/solution may have multilple configurations (Debug/Release, Win32/x64, and other custom configurations like "HighPerformance", "ForMobile", "ManagedDLL"), and you may like **not** to have set of source files get compiled. For, this you may put them into "Excludes".
- To put into exclusion, just select the source file (.CPP, .C), open property page for it, and set "Excluded from Build" to Yes. To make it part of build process (i.e. let it compile), set this property to No.
- Header Files need not to be put into exclusions, as they wont be compiled by compiler, it is just for programmer's view. Headers are only compiled when some source file do include them.